# Test rails controller concern in RSpec request spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

Say we have a controller concern like this:

```rb
module BillingErrorRescuer
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    rescue_from Billing::LimitExceeded, with: :rescue_billing_limits

    def rescue_billing_limits
      render status: 402, json: Billing::PlanPresenter.new(@account).to_json
    end
  end
end
```

We can test this separately in an anonymous controller in a **controller spec**:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe BillingErrorRescuer, type: :controller do
  controller do
    include BillingErrorRescuer

    def action
      @account = FactoryBot.create :account
      raise Billing::LimitExceeded
    end
  end

  before do
    routes.draw { get :action, to: "anonymous#action" }
    get :action
  end

  let(:account) { create :account, state: :trial }

  it 'renders json with billing data' do
    expect(response.body).to match_json_schema('controllers/billing_error_rescuer')
  end
end
```

How can I do the same thing in a **request spec**? More specifically, how can I create the route inside the request spec? I tried to replace the before block with

```rb
routes.draw { get :action, to: "anonymous#action" }
```

with an around block

```rb
around do |spec|
  set.draw do
    get :action, to: "anonymous#action"
  end
  spec.run
end
```

but doing a `get '/action'` gives me a 404.

Comment: I learned something by reading your question. Thank you!

Comment: QQ: Why? If you've already tested this code in a controller spec, why do you also need a request spec to test it? Are you trying to validate that the rescue from is present in a specific controller? Concerns are a built in feature of Rails. And, `included` is a built in feature of Ruby. No need to test those things. The Ruby and Rails teams have already don that for you.

Comment: @aridlehoover To move away from controller specs and move to request specs as [recommended by the rspec team](http://rspec.info/blog/2016/07/rspec-3-5-has-been-released/): 
“For new Rails apps: we don’t recommend adding the rails-controller-testing gem to your application. The official recommendation of the Rails team and the RSpec core team is to write request specs instead.”

Comment: Got it. Sorry. I got bupkis. But, thanks for the nugget of wisdom I gleaned from your question!